Configure path alias with latest Vite project and React
I'm starting a project with React using latest Vite project template:
npm create vite@latest my-app -- --template react-ts

The template contains 3 tsconfig files.
tsconfig.json
{
  "files": [],
  "references": [
   {"path": "./tsconfig.app.json"},
   {"path": "./tsconfig.node.json"}
  ]
}

tsconfig.node.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     "composite": true,
     "tsBuildInfoFile": "./node_modules/.tmp/tsconfig.node.tsbuildinfo",
     "skipLibCheck": true,
     "module": "ESNext",
     "moduleResolution": "bundler",
     "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
     "strict": true,
     "noEmit": true
   },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}

tsconfig.app.json
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "composite": true,
      "tsBuildInfoFile": "./node_modules/.tmp/tsconfig.app.tsbuildinfo",
      "target": "ES2020",
      "useDefineForClassFields": true,
      "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
      "module": "ESNext",
      "skipLibCheck": true,

      /* Bundler mode */
      "moduleResolution": "bundler",
      "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "isolatedModules": true,
      "moduleDetection": "force",
      "noEmit": true,
      "jsx": "react-jsx",

      /* Linting */
      "strict": true,
      "noUnusedLocals": true,
      "noUnusedParameters": true,
      "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
    },
  "include": ["src"]
}

Which of these files should I edit to configure the alias path? I tried to edit the tsconfig.app.json file adding these lines:
 "baseUrl": "./src",
 "paths": {
   "@pages/*": ["./pages/*"]
 }

This is my vite.config.ts file:
import { AliasOptions, defineConfig } from "vite";
import path from "path";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
      "@pages": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/pages"),
    } as AliasOptions,
  },
});

If I try to import a page like this:
import { Dashboard } from "@pages";

I get error: Cannot find module '@pages' or its corresponding type declarations.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

You should provide the directory and files structure.

One solution would be to remove the @pages alias and replace its references in imports by "@/pages", since they seem to be located directly under ./src. An other, since @ could be resolved prior in @pages, is to indicate the explicit replacement:
  root: "./src",  
  resolve: {
    alias:[
      { find: '@pages', replacement: resolve(__dirname,"/pages/") },
      { find: '@', replacement: resolve(__dirname,"/") }
    ]
  },


I recommend you use @/pages instead of @pages
then use vite-tsconfig-paths and define the absolute paths in tsconfig
then in your vite config:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [tsconfigPaths()],
})

